# Django Push Notification - Can't read ANPS certificate file

Tags: python, ios, django, apple-push-notifications, django-push-notifications

I am trying to implement push notification on my iOS app that uses a Django backend. I will explain some context before, in case it has revealing information. If you want to go to the problem directly, go the **The Problem** section.

### Context

Following this [tutorial](https://www.appcoda.com/push-notification-ios/), I have been able to verify that my certificates and provision profiles are correctly configured, as my device is in fact receiving push notifications sent by [APN Tester Free](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/apn-tester-free/id626590577?mt=12).

Of course, to make any sense, my Django backend will have to send the notifications. For this, I have installed [django-push-notifications](https://github.com/jleclanche/django-push-notifications). In my django settings file, I have set up the paths to the APNS certificate. This file needs to be a .pem file instead of the normal .cer file that the Apple developer portal exports.

To convert the .cer file, one can right click the Push Notification Certificate in **Keychain Access** and export a .p12 file. To convert the .p12 file to the required .pem, one needs to use **Terminal**, and run the following command:

```
openssl pkcs12 -in [export p12 file].p12 -out [final pem file].pem -nodes -clcerts
```

To make sure, my .pem file is actually working, I used the following command

```
openssl s_client -connect gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195 -cert [final pem file].pem -key [final pem file].pem
```

I seem to get a successful response (`CONNECTED(00000003)...`)

### The Problem

After installing django-push-notification, even though I am able to create `APNSDevice` instances, I cannot send messages. This is the error I receive:

```
File "/Users/joao/Code/code-vitae.com/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/push_notifications/models.py", line 93, in send_message
    return apns_send_message(registration_id=self.registration_id, alert=message, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joao/Code/code-vitae.com/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/push_notifications/apns.py", line 209, in apns_send_message
    _apns_send(registration_id, alert, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/joao/Code/code-vitae.com/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/push_notifications/apns.py", line 153, in _apns_send
    with closing(_apns_create_socket_to_push()) as socket:
  File "/Users/joao/Code/code-vitae.com/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/push_notifications/apns.py", line 58, in _apns_create_socket_to_push
    return _apns_create_socket((SETTINGS["APNS_HOST"], SETTINGS["APNS_PORT"]))
  File "/Users/joao/Code/code-vitae.com/env/lib/python3.4/site-packages/push_notifications/apns.py", line 46, in _apns_create_socket
    raise ImproperlyConfigured("The APNS certificate file at %r is not readable: %s" % (certfile, e))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The APNS certificate file at '/Users/joao/Documents/Circli/Certificates/Pro_Key.pem' is not readable: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe3 in position 4783: invalid continuation byte
```

This error makes me suspect that I somehow made an error when creating the pem file. But how is this so, if I can connect to the Apple push servers without trouble (as shown in the **Context**)?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a problem in the process that you use to convert the certificates.

Use [fastlane](http://fastlane.tools) to generate push certificates in needed format right away. Here is a [blog post](https://handcraftedios.com/2017/01/29/how-to-issue-apple-push-notifications-certificates-without-hassle/) covering whole process

Comment: This was a pain for such a long time, that I ended up using a PHP solution, for the notifications. I used the exact same PEM file, and it worked, so I'm pretty sure the certificate conversion was done correctly. Anyways, thanks for the tool (fastlane), seems very helpful.